# How do you tell if a window is modal or mdi window?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Given an window handle, is it possible to tell if the window is modal, or maybe an mdi child window?

Answer (score 2):

The following will return true if and only if the window is a MDI child window:

[GetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633584(VS.85).aspx)(Handle, GWL_EXTSTYLE) and [WS_EX_MDICHILD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543(VS.85).aspx) <> 0

Answer (score 1):

It would also appear that if a window doesn't have the WS_CHILD style then it is a dialog,modal window, or mdi child.

```
GetWindowLong(Handle, STYLE) and WS_CHILD != WS_CHILD
```